# PHP cant connect to LocalDb instance, ssms can

Tags: php, odbc, localdb

My php code is unable to connect to localdb instance. Am using Localdb19. I have tried creating datasource in odbc driver 17 and used datasource in php, even that didnt work. When i point my connection string to remote sql server it just works. What am missing here? i could connect to localdb instance from ssms and dotnet code.

Comment: Localdb only supports named pipes

Comment: I somehow got it working, by creating datasource in odbc. But now the problem is, when i connect to VPN it wont work. And also when i reboot the system it doesnt work initially.

Comment: Just use SQL Server Express with tcp instead